# Small Template-system, end of /if does not detect correct

Tags: php, html, regex

If i write the next line alone he cut's it for no reason, so...:

Hello,

i need help for this, i'm out of my knowledge.

i'm stuck at a small TPL-System which should do some foreach and if statements.
I do this in PHP but idk if this relevant.

https://regexr.com/62ho9 here you can see my issue. I want that the regex end by the second {/if} but it does not. Is there any possible solution to do this with regex?

If not, do you maybe have a good idea for PHP to do what i want? Because i'm out off ideas.

```
(?<={if \!TEST})([\s\S]*?)(?={\/if})
```

```html
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">
        {if !TEST}
          {USERNAME}
          {if !TEST}
            HI
          {/if} 
          klöaksdölsa
        {/if}

        asdas

        {if !TEST}asd{/if}
    </a>
```

At the moment i use {if ID statement} LOREM {/if ID} but the more elegant solution would be without an ID :D

(TEST: Hi guys) <-- because he cuts it every time from the start?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use recursion in PHP regex and the regex you could use is

```php
(?s){if\s+!TEST}((?:(?!{(?:if\s+!TEST|\/if)}).|(?R))*){\/if}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/3Buhq3/1/). You just need to get the Group 1 value after you get a match.

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - an `s` inline flag
- `{if\s+!TEST}`  - `{if`, one or more whitespaces, `!TEST}`
- `((?:(?!{(?:if\s+!TEST|\/if)}).|(?R))*)` - Group 1: zero or more occurrences of

  - `(?!{(?:if\s+!TEST|\/if)}).` - any char that is not the starting point of a `{if !TEST}` and `{/if}` char sequences
  - `|`
  - `(?R)` - the whole pattern recursed
- `{\/if}` - an `{/if}` substring.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to learn more regex. I didn't knew about that you can do this with plain regex.. :D